# Change SQL Server stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to add a new column in an existing stored procedure using C# and save it back to the SQL Server.

e.g. I have this SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SP1]
AS 
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE #tbl1(a int, b int)

  SELECT
     a, b
  FROM #tbl1
END
```

Now I want to automatically add a new column e.g. xx type TEXT, so the output is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SP1]
AS BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #tbl1
    (a int, b int, xx TEXT)

    SELECT
     a, b, xx
    FROM #tbl1
END
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking? How to modify a stored procedure using SQL, or how to send a SQL command to the server?

Comment: @Adam Robinson - He's not asking either of those, he is asking how to create actual parameters from within managed code (C#).

Comment: @Adam Robinson - Adam either can be done alter or create.  So it doesn't matter.  The point is the OP is trying to add a sproc parameter within C#.  I'm not saying I would do this, I am just saying that is what he / she wants to do.

Answer (score 3):

When you've defined your database object and a stored procedure object you can create the sp right from managed code:

```
StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure(myDB, "NameOfSproc");
sp.TextMode=False;
sp.AnsiNullsStatus=False;
sp.QuotedIdentifierStatus=false;

//add some parameters
StoredProcedureParameter p;
p = new StoredProcedureParameter(sp, "@MyID", Int);

//add the parameters to the sproc
sp.Parameters.Add(p);
sp.TextBody = "SELECT blah FROM MyTable WHERE ID=@myID";
sp.CreatE();
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, that is incomplete example code. Your SP will return an empty resultset.

To answer a underlying question: How do I execute a DDL statement, I suggest this answer.

- Create your SQL script as a String.
- Create a SqlConnection to your database and open it.
- Create an SqlCommand object. Set its Text property to your script string. Set its Connection property to your SqlConnection object.
- Call the ExecuteNonQuery() method on your SqlCommand object.

It's just like running a query, except executing a create/alter script returns no results.

> Note per JonH: nothing was mentioned about using command parameters or stored procedure parameters, so I didn't address either of them. This was a short-and-simple method to alter a stored procedure - that is, run an SQL script to do so - from C#.

Your script string can be constructed using any method you choose. If you are talking about dynamically parsing a stored procedure from a database, reassembling it with altered parts, then resubmitting it, you should probably revise the way you asked your question. You would have to know the structure of your script; there's no general way to "insert a column in unspecified places in some existing SP".

Comment: That is how to run a stored procedure, not how to actually create parameters on the sproc from managed code.

Comment: @John- Why not?  Assuming he's preventing injection attacks in some other way, modifying the stored procedure this way would work just fine.  Although, if constructing/altering the stored procedure in C# (or any code) makes you nervous, just pass all of that in as a comma-separated paramter, break it apart in the procedure, and spit back the results.

Comment: @MAW74656 - I misread the steps, I do see that Suncat2000 mentioned to set the text property to the script so yes that does work as well.  Suncat2000 can you make a small edit to the post so I can resubmit the vote ?

Comment: I added a note clarifying that nothing in my post nor in the original question addressed using parameters.