# Read and alter Sql Server object in c#

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I have written one sample Sql stored procedure.

```
  USE [Db]
  GO   

  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  GO
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_TestProcedure] 
  AS
  BEGIN

     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     PRINT 'Good evening'
 END
```

Its working fine. Now I want to read and alter this stored procedure (and db object like function and view) using c#. Can it be done using c# ? 
I am using  Server 2014 and C#4.5.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972363/change-sql-server-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp

Comment: @ Massimiliano : Thank you for quick reply. But, this is not the solution I want. Here it is given as how to create stored procedure on fly. I have already created the stored procedure and want to modify it. For example, I want to add one line 'With Encryption' in the procedure.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not now what SQL SERVER you have but for SQL 2014 x64 it will be:

1. Here you have link to ms files to download: [Get it from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42295)
   You need to check from list:

ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi

ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi

Download it install and reboot.

2. Here you have whole code for method (**Please change sql connection string parameters to your server connection string in this procedure**):

   ```
   public static bool RunScriptsInTransaction(string script)
   {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
       con.ConnectionString = "Server=YourSqlServer;Initial Catalog = YourDbName;User Id=YourUserName;Password=YourPassword;";
       con.Open();

       ServerConnection sCon = new ServerConnection(con);
       sCon.BeginTransaction();
       try
       {
           sCon.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
           sCon.CommitTransaction();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           sCon.RollBackTransaction();
           return false;
       }
       finally
       {
           con.Close();
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```

To run it just write:

```
        RunScriptsInTransaction(@"
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_TestProcedure] 
      AS
      BEGIN

         SET NOCOUNT ON;
         PRINT 'Good evening'
     END

    GO
    ");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, here I dont know what will be inside the procedure. I mean to say, user will give the name of the procedure and programmatically I need to modify it.Here, my question is how can I read the content of stored procedure in c# from Sql server ? Whatever the code you have provided is the second part of my requirement. Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Arkadiusz for showing me right way.. I found this link and got to know some more things                                                                http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d3e4b1/dynamically-getting-stored-procedures-collection-from-sql-se/         thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use DDL in C# probably: [Click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799.aspx)
If you want to do it in C# you have to use ServerConnection not standard SqlConnection. Look at this example:

```
    public bool RunScriptsInTransaction(string script)
    {
        ServerConnection sCon = new ServerConnection(this.m_dbConnection);
        sCon.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            sCon.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
            sCon.CommitTransaction();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            sCon.RollBackTransaction();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

You have to add references to use ServerConnction:

[image]

Maybe you will need to install SQLSysClrTypes, SharedManagementObject and reboot  machine where you want to run it.

Comment: Yes ... can you provide me complete example or link to follow ?